# JS: How to add empty option ; JQuery options.filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I try to adapt this code: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9cjmLg/5/

how can I add an empty option value so that the first option is empty and the user must select a option?

I try append and add() but $("#patient").on("change") do not work anymore

```
   sel.on('change', function () {
        selected_site = this.value;
        var value = site_abbreviation(parseInt(selected_site));
        var options = $("#patients option");
        options.hide();
        var op = options.filter(function () {
            return value == $(this).val().slice(4,6);
        }).show();
        op.add(<option></option>)
        $("#patients").val(op.eq(0).val());
    })
```

```
    $("#patients").on("change", function(event){
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#patients").data("patient-url"),
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'patient' : $(this).val(),  
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data)
                $("#information_patient").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are breaking javascript, you should get a console error in F12 developer tools.

it seems your problem is in this line

```
    op.add(<option></option>)
```

should be -- edit -- should also be another funciton to add it the first item

```
    op.prepend($('<option></option>'))
```

then in your `<select>` tag you should have the `required` attribute and browser will automatically detect the empty value as incorrect like

```
<select required id="xxx">
....
</select>
```

Comment: i've edited probably you are appending to last child instead of first child

Comment: prepend add <option></option> before text of all <option> ; it should be add but does not work

Comment: ```<option value="" selected="selected"></option>``` in the template and```$("#patients option[value]").filter(function() {
        return +$(this).val() != "";
}).hide();``` in JS but the empty option is present but not selected by default

Comment: Is the empty option the first item on select list?

Comment: yes ; I try $("#patients")[0].selectedIndex = 0; and $("#patients option:first").attr('selected','selected').change(); but partially works: at first load page it works but after it is random... I should have a special case I do not manage...

Comment: Probably is as you say, browser will automatically select the first option loaded if no option has selected attribute, if it change after page load it means that anywhere you are changing it's selected option or you are no longer appending the empty option

Answer (score 0):

If the user must select an option then show the first option. If that option is correct for user then they will leave it, otherwise they will select the proper option. I think that if the option is a required field, then show only the possible options, don't add an empty option or like select option.

To add an empty option:

```
$("#select").prepend(`<option></option>`)
```

Comment: No I want the user choose the option and the option selected call an ajax request that display informations related to the option selected ; prepend is not the correct method

Answer (score 0):

here the way I do
I add class "hide" to the options I need to filter and leav an empty option without this class
it seems to work even if I don't if it is the best way to achieve the expected result

```
<select name="patients" class="form-control" id="patients" data-patient-url="{% url 'randomization:patient' %}">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for patient in patients %}
        <option class="hide" value="{{ patient.ran_num }}">{{ patient.ran_num }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

```
    $(function(){
        if($("#site").length){

            var selected_site = sel[0].value // sit_ide
            var value = site_abbreviation(parseInt(selected_site));
            var options = $("#patients option .hide");
            options.hide();
            var op = options.filter(function () {
                return value == $(this).val().slice(4,6);
            }).show();
            $("#patients").val(op.eq(0).val());
        }
    });
```